# How to run a script on ElasticSearch before indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to add/update some fields in the document before indexing. How can I do?

I came across this question because the documents are sent from other applications and I should not touch these. The simplest thing I can think of is writing a script to manipulate the document before indexing.

Comment: Does this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098314/elasticsearch-run-script-on-document-insertion-insert-api meet your needs?

Comment: Transform is great for my case http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html